# Difference between += -1 and -= 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I make an animation with this movement code:

`x += -1`

I'm just wondering what the difference is if i write this:

`x -= 1`

the result is still the same, but before i move any futher, is there are any difference in essence between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the same thing. it is like doing in math "a + -1" and "a-1"

Comment: IMO I prefer read `x -=`  if the logic is to sub on x

Answer (score 8):

`x += -1` is shorthand for `x = x + -1` while `x -= 1` is shorthand for `x = x - 1`. This will produce the same result as long as x is a javascript `Number`. But because `+` can also be used for string concatenation, consider x being the `String` `'5'` for example and we will have this situation:

`'5' + -1 = '5-1'` and  `'5' - 1 = 4`.

So it might be advisable to think twice before choosing which one instead of just blindly using them interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there are nothing more than shorthand operators. In the first case, it's an [Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), in the second case it's a [Subtraction Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment).

So your code `x += -1` can be interpreted as follows:

```
x = x + -1; // which is the same as..
x = x - 1;  // which can be rewritten as..
x -= 1;
```

Comment: `x + -1` and `x - 1` are not the same in JS, see the @henrikmerlander's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically there is no difference. 2 + -1 = 1 which is the same as 2 - 1 = 1